# CSS Set background image in heading

Tags: html, css

I want to set an image as a background of a heading, but only in the empty area. I do not want to display any background where the heading text is.
So, I have following HTML for heading:

```
<h2><span>Some text</span></h2>

h2{
    background: url("image.png");
}
```

The problem is that, I do not want to display this heading background in the span, instead I want the span to adapt the background image of the page (parent element). I can not set a specific specific background for the span because it won't match with the page background. So how can I solve this?

Comment: You can't. As far as I know. I'll give it a shot though

Comment: You should set background color for <span>.

Comment: Madara is right. You can't mask in HTML/CSS. You will need to apply the background to different elements that dont overlap with the `span`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to coordinate the background position of the image with the text. I'm not sure what your exact layout is, so adjust your values accordingly.

CSS alone cannot detect where your text is, or how bit it is. You need to use JavaScript to do that.

```
h2 {
    background: url(image.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:5px 5px;
    padding-left:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use psuedo element to achieve this,

```
   h1:before 
 {
 content:url(your_img.jpg);
 }
```